# Multicasting Error: Multicast Address Not Found

Tags: java, soap, soap-client, multicast, multicastsocket

I am trying to create a SOAP Client. but keep getting this error. Any ideas why? I tried changing the IP but still same error.

[image]

MulticastSocket.Java

```
  public void joinGroup(InetAddress mcastaddr) throws IOException {
    if (isClosed()) {
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    }

    checkAddress(mcastaddr, "joinGroup");
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkMulticast(mcastaddr);
    }

    if (!mcastaddr.isMulticastAddress()) {
        throw new SocketException("Not a multicast address");
    }
```

SOAPClient.java

```
public class MultiThread extends Thread implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    MulticastSocket socket;
    DatagramPacket packet;

    public MultiThread() throws IOException {
        socket = new MulticastSocket(4446);
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("122.57.153.213");
        socket.joinGroup(group);
    }
```

SOAPCLient.java @ line 80

```
public SoapClient() throws IOException, RemoteException, NotBoundException, NamingException {      
    setBackground(new Color(0, 153, 76));//three green lines on gui
    JPanel rightSideLayout = new JPanel();//active clients
    rightSideLayout.setBackground(Color.darkGray);    
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());//contains typing field and send button

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    Font font = label.getFont();
    Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
    attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
    font  = Font.getFont(attributes);
    label.setFont(font);
    label.setText("\tBhoo Online");
    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

    sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(RIGHT_PANEL_WIDTH, 20));
    line 80   sendButton.addActionListener(new MultiThread());
    mainField = new JTextArea();
```

SOAPClient.java (main)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, RemoteException, NotBoundException, NamingException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BhooChat Client");
    SoapClient bhooChat = new SoapClient();
    frame.add(bhooChat);
```

Answer (score 3):

The IP address being passed to `joinGroup` is not a valid multicast address.

Valid IPv4 multicast addresses are in the range 224.0.0.1 - 239.255.255.255.

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried changing it a few times i.e. 224.0.0.1 & 224.0.0.100 and it then says can't assign address? would that be because I'm using a Mac? @dbush

Comment: @kiwilifter It's possible that the interface it's trying to join on doesn't allow multicast.  Before calling `joinGroup`, first call `setInterface` and pass it the IP of the interface you want to join on.  Also, run `ifconfig -a` on the command line to see which interfaces support multicast and which ones don't.

Answer (score 1):

As dbush stated, 122.57.153.213 is not a multicast address.

224.0.0.1 is a well known address

224.0.0.69  to 224.0.0.100 is reserved

http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml

Try an address like 239.192.0.1